# Oracle Sequence start with doubt

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I am trying to autonumber Id field in one of my table. Table already has 40 rows of data but now if i autonumber the id field do i have to specify start with as 41 or not? Thank you

Do i have to do this

```
create sequence EMP.SEQ_ID
minvalue 1
maxvalue 99999999999999999
start with 41
increment by 1
cache 50
order;
```

or only this will work

```
create sequence EMP.SEQ_ID
minvalue 1
maxvalue 99999999999999999
increment by 1
cache 50
order;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify `START WITH`, it starts at 1.

So if you are using this for a primary key and there are already rows with IDs from 1 to 40, it will fail.

PS: You can use this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMP.SEQ_ID
START WITH 41
NOMAXVALUE
CACHE 50;
```

(it increments by 1 by default).